# How can I bind command from MainViewModel to my Menu.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, reactive, avalonia

Now I have this axaml:

`<Menu
Background="#1A1E27"

> 

```
<MenuItem
    Header="Open"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
>
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem
                Header="{Binding Path=Name}"
            >
                <MenuItem.Styles>
                    <Style
                        Selector="MenuItem MenuItem"
                    >
                        <Setter
                            Property="Command"
                            Value="{Binding OpenProjectCommand}"
                        />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Styles> 
            </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

`

`Projects` is the object of type `ObservableCollection<Project>`. That axaml code is calling my `OpenProjectCommand` method from `Project` class. Could you help me please, how can I set up DataContext to call `OpenProjectCommand` method from my `ViewModel` (not from `Project` class)?

I've tried to use `$parent` alias to set DataContext, but it didn't help me. Maybe there are other ways to do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77878872/12473121